# Mule 3.7 until successful failureExpression not working

Tags: web-services, http, mule

I am using until-successful to retry calling a web service only when it is down.
Below is what I have tried:

```
<until-successful maxRetries="10" failureExpression="#[(message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200) &amp;&amp; (message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 500)]" synchronous="true" millisBetweenRetries="5000">

<flow-ref name="callSubFlow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
```

If I get a HTTP response 500 I also do not want to retry calling the web service.  I have mocked a web service and when it returns a HTTP 500 response the until successful keeps retrying calling the web service.  What is wrong with the failureExpression above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how if fixed my issue.  I created another flow that catches only the Web Service 500 error.  The until -successful then does not retry to call the web service again.

```
<until-successful maxRetries="${webservice.timeout.max.retries}" failureExpression="#[exception != null &amp;&amp; (exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException) || exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException) || exception.causedBy(java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException) || exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketException))]" 
synchronous="true" millisBetweenRetries="5000" >
 <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">


      <set-payload value="#[payLoad]" />
      <flow-ref name="Flow1" />

  </processor-chain>
</until-successful>

<flow name="Flow1">
<ws:consumer config-ref="WSConsumerConfig" operation="execute"  />
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">


      <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" when="#[exception != null &amp;&amp; exception.causedBy(org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException)]">

        <logger message="SoapFaultException occurred." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="#[exception]" doc:name="Set Payload"></set-payload>
     </catch-exception-strategy>

    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of confusion around this expression. As per documentation,

FAILURE : "A message processor within the until-successful scope throws an exception or contains an exception payload. Also, if an expression is provided in the attribute failureExpression and it evaluates to true."

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/until-successful-scope#success-and-failure

The catch here is that with the current implementation of Mule 'failureExpression' is checked and used **when no exception is thrown**. Otherwise it does always retry in case of exception. Solution for your problem would be to have a catch block for particular exception and then set a property, in failureExpression evaluate that property to retry in until successful. Basically, you would be using recursion technique kind of code for retrying.

Example for your code:

```
<until-successful maxRetries="10" failureExpression="#[flowVars['errorInActualOutboundFlow']]" synchronous="true" millisBetweenRetries="5000">
   <flow-ref name="callActualOutboundFlow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</until-successful>
```

Actual Outbound Flow:

```
 <flow name="callActualOutboundFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">        
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy"> 
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" when="#[exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException)]">
           <logger message="#### Until-Successful will retry in this case " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
           <set-variable variableName="errorInActualOutboundFlow" value="#[true]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-variable variableName="errorInActualOutboundFlow" value="#[false]" doc:name="Copy_of_Variable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to tell HTTP Request component that `500` is the Non-failure scenario in this case. Because By default `200` is the success scenario, other than anything needs to be mention in 'success-status-code-validator'.

```
<until-successful maxRetries="5" synchronous="true" doc:name="Until Successful" failureExpression="#[  message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200  &amp;&amp; message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 500     ]" millisBetweenRetries="1000">
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="test1" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:success-status-code-validator values="200,500"/>. 
        </http:request>
</until-successful>
```

Instead of Directly using HTTP here, Believe you used  `callSubFlow` there where you used HTTP-request, mention in  `<http:success-status-code-validator values="200,500"/>` as success. So it don't retry in this case, works as expected.
If you want to handle `500` as separate logic other than 200, you can do condition check after `http:request` by checking its message.inboundProperties['http.status'] and can proceed with logic based on `200` or `500`.

It is failed in your case, because Http-request saying '500' as failure and Until mentioned as Non-failure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am using a Web Service Consumer like: <ws:consumer-config name="WSConsumerConfig" wsdlLocation="${wsdl.location}"
    service="Service" port="HttpPort" serviceAddress="${service.url}"
    connectorConfig="HTTPRequestConfiguration" doc:name="Web Service Consumer">
  </ws:consumer-config>  I just need to figure out where to add the http:success-status-code-validator.  My http config is: <http:request-config name="HTTPRequestConfiguration" responseTimeout="${service.timeout}" host="${service.url}"
    doc:name="HTTPRequestConfiguration">